# How to configure Webpack to build without importing an external module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I Have a third-party library needed to be used in project ts code, which is added to the application using a CDN path in the HTML. And this library is exporting a window variable, which is used in the code.

The package is not available as an npm module. While running the webpack build it's failing with the following error message:
`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CUSTOM_WINDOW_VARIABLE'.`

I have added this in name in the webpackconfig.js file as :

```
    externals: {
      CUSTOM_WINDOW_VARIABLE: "CUSTOM_WINDOW_VARIABLE",
    },
```

But still getting the same error.

How to tell webpack to ignore these global variables while building. Or convert them to `window.CUSTOM_WINDOW_VARIABLE` from `CUSTOM_WINDOW_VARIABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know your problem is not about `webpack` at all. The issue is most likely throwing from `ts-loader` which uses `tsc` compiler your `tsx?` files so in order to fix this issue you might need to define the type for your global value which is available on `window` as following steps:

- Create your project typing dir and the file `types/global.d.ts` (you can name whatever you want, feel free to use my suggested name in terms of no idea how to name it) with following content:

```
// global.d.ts

// You can define your own type by replacing with the exact type
declare const CUSTOM_WINDOW_VARIABLE: any;
```

- Make sure your `tsconfig.json` which is placed at repo's root dir in most cases includes your `types` dir by adding to `include` config option:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": ["types", ...]
}
```

Hopefully it would work for your case

*PS: If you don't `import` your library as `externals`, basically you don't have to configure the `externals` property in your `webpack.config` file*